# Sound effects play while audio background is playing Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

im currently new at making VB and i would like to ask if how to play sound effects while a background music is playing, for example, while a background music is playing, when i click the button it produces a sound effects. as far as i did, when i hover my mouse on the button, the current background music stops and the sound effect executes and after i hover my mouse, the background music plays agaian

here is my code..

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        My.Computer.Audio.Play("C:\Users\android_kh5sy35fe2\Desktop\WWM\auswahlrunde_loop.wav",
            AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseHover
        My.Computer.Audio.Play("C:\Users\android_kh5sy35fe2\Desktop\WWM\Hawking.wav",
            AudioPlayMode.Background)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseLeave
        My.Computer.Audio.Play("C:\Users\android_kh5sy35fe2\Desktop\WWM\auswahlrunde_loop.wav",
                AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.MouseHover
        My.Computer.Audio.Play("C:\Users\android_kh5sy35fe2\Desktop\WWM\Finn.wav",
            AudioPlayMode.Background)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.MouseLeave
        My.Computer.Audio.Play("C:\Users\android_kh5sy35fe2\Desktop\WWM\auswahlrunde_loop.wav",
                AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.MouseHover
        My.Computer.Audio.Play("C:\Users\android_kh5sy35fe2\Desktop\WWM\Homer.wav",
            AudioPlayMode.Background)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.MouseLeave
        My.Computer.Audio.Play("C:\Users\android_kh5sy35fe2\Desktop\WWM\auswahlrunde_loop.wav",
                AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
    End Sub
End Class
```

thanks for the replies.. cheers!

Comment: sorry about the tags

Answer (score 0):

`My.Computer.Audio.Play` is unique (**static**).
You can use a [`SoundPlayer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), that is a **class**, so you can instantiate it multiple times (for each sound).

```
Dim music As String = "" ' *.wav file location
Dim media As New Media.SoundPlayer(music)
media.Play() ' Async, creates a new thread
```

---

```
Dim sound As String = "" ' *.wav file location
Dim media As New Media.SoundPlayer(sound)
media.PlaySync() ' Sync, locks the current thread
```